# Electron: Notification is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, electron

I am trying to initialize an object of [Notification](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/notification) provided by electron. But I am getting the error as:
`Uncaught Exception:
TypeError: electron.Notification is not a constructor`

I am doing this in `Main` process.

Code:

```
const electron = require('electron');
new electron.Notification({ title: "Cue", body: "Hello" }).show();
```

Electron version: `2.0.2/2.0.3`

Any clues or ideas?

Comment: have you tried `new Notification()` rather than `new electron.Notification()`?

Comment: @phuzi yup gives me `not defined`.

Comment: which version of electron you're using?

Comment: @OJKwon 2.0.2/2.0.3

Comment: try debugging your code. What is `electron.Notification`? Is it `undefined`?

Comment: @pushkin Yes it is coming as undefined, but at the same time, `electron.BrowserWindow`, `electron.BrowserView` is not `undefined`, and working fine. Also when I print `electron` in console. It prints this { clipboard , crashReporter , nativeImage , shell , app , autoUpdater , BrowserView , BrowserWindow , contentTracing , dialog , globalShortcut , ipcMain , Menu , MenuItem , net , powerMonitor , powerSaveBlocker , protocol , screen , session , systemPreferences , TouchBar , Tray , webContents  }`

Comment: @AkashdeepSaluja Why do you mean your version is 2.0.2 **/** 2.0.3. What does it say in your package.json? Maybe trying running `npm install`?

Comment: @pushkin It means I tied both versions. Tried npm install by clearing out node_modules but no luck.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173767/discussion-between-akashdeep-saluja-and-pushkin).

Answer (score 8):

I think you should write

```
new electron.remote.Notification({....})
```

instead of

```
new electron.Notification({....})
```